# search for regex in text using python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to search for region in s1 . I want to return 1 if i the text contains  "region" or "région" or "regions" or "régions" and 0 in the other case.
i wrote the code below but it does'nt work

`s1 = pd.Series(['here is region', 'my regions', 'régionally', 'région','régions','regions','region'])
s1.str.contains('r.gion[s][^a-zA-Z]', regex=True).astype(int)`
In this case the result must be

`[1,1,0,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: Use `s1.str.contains(r'\br[ée]gions?\b').astype(int)`

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would expect all those entries to contain the regex...

Comment: thank you but is there a manner to use regex without (r') because i aimed to put the regex in file cvs and then read it from csv

Comment: `s1.str.contains(variableincsvFile, regex=True).astype(int)`

Comment: @This Yes, `\br[ée]gions?\b` is what you need to write in the file.

Comment: but my file contains 3 other regex and i must do a join on the 4 regex

Comment: `listt = ['Hello',\br[ée]gions?\b,'[mM]orning']   variableincsvFile = "|".join(listt) `

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do you see what i mean? please

Comment: If you write the regexps in a text file each on a line, then, after collecting all the values in a list, your code will work fine.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer since it does what you asked for. Else, add details to the question if you have trouble implementing this and let know via a comment with @username in it

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
s1.str.contains(r'\br[ée]gions?\b').astype(int)
```

If you want to save the regex in a file and then read in and use as a variable just write `\br[ée]gions?\b` there.

Test:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.Series(['here is region', 'my regions', 'régionally', 'région','régions','regions','region'])
>>> s1.str.contains(r'\br[ée]gions?\b').astype(int)
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int32
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `r` - `r` char
- `[ée]` - one of the letters in the character class
- `gion` - `gion`
- `s?` - an optional `s` letter
- `\b` - a word boundary.